# How to resolve this DNS, rocketchat, webservers routing issue?

Tags: rocket.chat

So I have a few servers:

- Server1(winserver2016): Webapplication1 on IIS port 80 + 443, Webapplication2 Apache port 9000 + 9001
- Server2(ubuntu16.4): Rocketchat snap, OpenVPN
- 2 Domain controllers (winserver2016) and a purchased dns record from godaddy domain.co.uk.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to redirect HTTPS requests to the internal servers via port 443 on the router tried a reverse proxy in IIS 10 with aarp and rewrite (nothing) I tried using subdomains on godaddy but it just redirects to to the IPaddress:port. tried adding subdomains in DNS nothing still the same response 404

Essentially if I point port 80 and 443 at rocket chat it works and I get SSL via caddy but if I try to connect any other services on those ports I get nothing returned. If I connect rocket chat on ports 3000 and 8443 for example I get no SSL and the https site for it doesn't work

I am ready to try a reverse proxy on another Linux deploy in a min and see how that goes but I suspect it will be the same result.

All of these servers run on Hyper-V on 2 win10 boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to redirect based on source IP, You might have to use policy routes in the firewall to control the behavior depending on the source of the packet. I'd check to see if your firewall or router has such abilities. Cheap routers tend to use basic static routing

If that doesn't help, you might also need to have a separate reverse proxy web server in place. The configuration is a little tricky in apache...You could put the following inside a virtual host block if you wanted to route based on sub-directory:

```
 <Proxy balancer://myset>
 # xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your server that will be behind the proxy
 BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/subdirectoryName/
 ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPreservehost On
 ProxyPass "/subdirectoryName/"  "balancer://myset/"
 ProxyPassReverse "/subdirectoryName/"  "balancer://myset/"
```

Not sure if this what would work exactly for subdomains, but I'd try something like this.